# PyCharm Run Doesn't Recognize Packages But Console and Terminal Are OK

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

Running PyCharm 2020.1.2 Community Edition in Win10 with a Python 3.6 venv as interpreter. Installed the package feature-engine through the Project Interpret interface, installs fine and appears in the list. I can successfully `import feature_engine` in the PyCharm console, and I can use it fine. I can also execute a .py file with this import statement in the Terminal with the venv activated, and it also works fine. However, when I try to Run the same .py file with the import statement, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'feature_engine'
```

I have tried using **import** and importlib, thinking the issue was the hyphen, but those didn't work. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, restarting PyCharm, etc. Nothing seems to work. Any suggestions how to get the Run function working?

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions. Attached are the Run configuration and the Project interpreter configuration. As far as I can tell, the environment is the same.

[image: Interpreter Config]

[image: Run Config]

Below are examples of the error trace. The object being Run is a Flask app, which imports packages that use the feature-engine library. The actual import statement in the final import is simply `import feature_engine`. Trying to import the method directly using `from feature_engine import variable_transformers as vt` also fails.

[image: General import statement]

[image: From package import statement]

Comment: is your Pycharm interpreter configured the same as your terminal's interpreter? I suspect they are in different environments

Comment: Can you check if the project interpreter is configured correctly?

Comment: @ori6151, thanks for your help. I have edited to show the project interpreter and run configs.

Comment: @HelenustheSeer Can you show the portion of the code where you try to import and use it ?

Comment: @heretolearn Thanks again, I have added screenshots. The import statement itself is simply 'import feature_engine', but 'from feature_engine import foo' also fails. However, both of these work fine in the Console.

Comment: @heretolearn I just noticed something. When I modified the code to make use of the general 'import feature_engine' approach in the above edit, it became 'tf = feature_engine.variable_transformers.YeoJohnsonTransformer()', PyCharm then flagged it with the message " Cannot find reference 'variable_transformers' in '__init__.py' ". When I execute that command in the Console, it works fine despite the warning; but maybe this message reveals why Run doesn't like it?

Comment: @HelenustheSeer  Instead of `tf = feature_engine.variable_transformers.YeoJohnsonTransformer()'` Can you try this `import  feature_engine.variable_transformers as vt    vt.YeoJohnsonTransformer()` The issue may be because of the way it is imported. I personally haven't used this library but from the documents and sample usage i found they suggest using this way. Hope this helps.

Comment: @heretolearn, thanks so much for your help, but sadly this still gave the error 'No module named 'feature_engine'. This method was just a wrapper for the scipy.stats method anyway, so it was easy to bypass this issue just by using scipy.stats directly. But there are other methods I wanted to use in the package, so I am disappointed I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right configuration to build your program (that is, using the python executable of the right enviroment). You can check this in the top right corner, where the run button is.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the OP to show the configs, do you see anything wrong?